# mercurialeclipse not showing complete history

Tags: eclipse, mercurial, mercurialeclipse

I've shuffled things around, moving my files to another directory. Now when I click Show History, I only see the branch that I moved the files in. 
I'm using eclipse neon, latest version of the mercuraleclipse plugin.

Here are the changes I made. There are old projects that have the source (.java) files in the top-level. So I created a src directory and used hg move to move the files under src. Once I did this, when I click on a file to see the history, It only shows the one change in the new mercurial branch I made the change in.

Comment: I removed the update site from my sites list. Then re-added the same url using http://bitbucket.org/mercurialeclipse/update-site/raw/default/. This time, eclipse "refreshed" and the version mentioned from 10/2016 appeared in the experimental section. I installed it and the show history is showing everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing that comes to mind is which version of MercurialEclipse are you using?

I'm asking because I have solved [this very issue](https://bitbucket.org/mercurialeclipse/main/issues/485/mercurial-history-does-not-show-across) a few months ago in the official MercurialEclipse repository. The fix required also making a small change to the library that hgE uses, namely *javahg*.

Also, maybe that it'll help to have this in your `.hgrc` file (this file is in `C:\Users\theUserName` on my Windows 8.1 system. Please, refer to the [Mercurial documentation](https://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html) for other systems)

```
[defaults]
log = -f
addremove = --similarity 100
commit = -A
```

I'm not sure that `log = -f` is pertinent to this issue but I have these lines in my file. I can't believe I didn't comment each of these so as to know why each is necessary or useful. Since the fix on August 31, `commit = -A` is no longer necessary , but I keep it in the file just in case I use  `hg` on the command line.

As a rule of thumb, you may also check directly on the command line whether any problem you encounter with hgE also shows up with `hg`. That will provide the team as a whole with some useful insight.

**Make sure that you use a build of hgE from after that date**. If you still have this problem later on, please open an issue on the BitBucket tracker with as many details as possible. I'll fix the problem and we'll update this question with the solution/answer.

Comment: I haven't forgotten this question I just been swamped at work. I will get to this soon. Thanks!

Comment: I will add this, according to Eclipse Market place, I have installed mercurialEclipse 2.2 and mercurialeclipse (was: HgEclipse) 1.8.

Comment: I've verified the hg command line shows full history while mercurialeclipse only shows the branch where the move took place.

Comment: I'm confused. You wrote "I will add this, according to Eclipse Market place, I have installed mercurialEclipse 2.2 and mercurialeclipse (was: HgEclipse) 1.8" and I read "mercurialeclipse" twice in that with only one character case different :-) The time of hgEclipse is long past. Could you share the full version number you see in Help > Installation Details > Installed Software for the line with id "mercurialeclipse.feature.group"? Make sure you have only one MercurialEclipse variant installed.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Here is the version info you requested.   MercurialEclipse 2.2.0.201605140822 mercurialeclipse.feature.group MercurialEclipse project

Comment: I install MercurialEclipse using the eclipse market place. Is there another update site I should be using?

Comment: I removed the update site and re-added it. This time the version you spoke of appeared in the experimental versions. I installed that version and the show history shows all.

Comment: Nice. I'm glad to hear that.

Comment: I can no longer commit changes from the team synchronizing view.

Comment: Please open a new issue in the issue tracker on BitBucket. Give your OS, a screenshot of your Installed Software and any details to reproduce your issue.